# Помогите откатить изменения (git)

Tags: git

Ребенок удалил файлы на ноутбуке, но на гитхабе успела закомитить последние правильные изменения. т.е. я сделала коммит (последний), а после этого файлы удилили. как лучше поступить?

Comment: Какие файлы удалили? Если ещё остался локальный репозиторий в скрытой папке `.git`, можно восстановить оттуда (`git checkout -- .`), в противном случае всегда есть возможность склонировать репу заново.

Comment: я набрала git reset --hard HEAD и мне откатило, папка появилась, но содержание файлов не правильное) даже кодировка другая какая то. че делать то?!

Comment: Склонируйте репозиторий заново. Это будет быстрее